# How to use PBKDF2 password hashing in an embedded Linux device

Tags: linux, crypt, busybox, pbkdf2, password-hash

I have a need to generate password hashes in a Windows application and, at a later time, download them to a Linux device to be inserted into the shadow password file. For marketing reasons using PBKDF2 is attractive at the Windows end as it provides a level of FIPS certification, but I do not know how/if we can use a PBKDF2 hash in the Linux shadow password file.

An odd requirement I know, but the Windows app is used to off-line configure the RBAC.

I know next to nothing about Linux, but my understanding is that we use Busybox (which includes crypt) and PBKDF2 is not supported.

Can PBKDF2 support be added? Pointers as to how?